# Comparing each variable in a list to each variable in another list

Tags: python-2.7, function, loops, pandas

Is there a way to compare each variable in a list to each variable in another list on python. Without writing it out by using a loop or a function I've tried both and looked for different types of functions without any luck but I'm still pretty new at this.

```
a = [1,4,6,2,9]
b = [3,7,12,8,10,35]

1>3,1>7,1>12 etc.. 4>3,4>7,4>12 etc...
```

and so on and so fourth. But without having to write it all out like that.

I'm just curious. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) will get you all the pairings:

```
import itertools
itertools.product(a, b)
```

That's a generator, so you can put `list()` around it and get this:

```
[(1, 3),
 (1, 7),
 (1, 12),
 (1, 8),
 (1, 10),
 (1, 35),
 (4, 3),
 (4, 7),
 ...
```

Then you can feed that through [`operator.gt`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.gt) to get the boolean results:

```
import operator
itertools.starmap(operator.gt, itertools.product(a, b))
```

Put that into a `list()` and you have:

```
[True,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 True,
 False,
 True,
 ...
```